# Can "trustable" be used in IELTS Academic writing?

Tags: writing, formal-language, ielts

There was [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234193/trustable-or-trustworthy) about *trustable* and it was mentioned that it started to be used more often only [recently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trustable&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrustable%3B%2Cc0). Thus, I am a bit worried about its usage in IELTS Academic writing.

Like an example from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trustable):

> a trustable source

The question: Can I use *trustable* in IELTS Academic writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster does define "trustable" as an extant word (https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/trustable), but still, it would certainly seem odd to many people and hence other words such as "reliable", "trustworthy" and "bankable" are much more preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is a tendency to use adjectives with 'able'-ending both in speaking and writing. Words such as DOABLE, WORKABLE, COACHABLE, MANAGEABLE are commonplace. That being said, I don't feel that trustable is in this shortlist yet. So, if I were you I would stick to RELIABLE, CREDIBLE instead.

As for common mistakes and words choice for IELTS, I would recommend Facebook page [@tuto.ielts](https://www.facebook.com/tuto.ielts).
It features typical writing mistakes, so it can be useful.

Disclosure: I make regular contributions to that page which link I provided so I would be happy to see you there.

Comment: I notice that you are promoting that Facebook URL in your answers. You should read over [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/273494) You *must* disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers.